# Hide a pricing box using :nth-child(x) CSS

Tags: html, css

I have some pricing boxes on this page:

https://www.shiftdivorceguide.com/pricing-plan/

Following code hides the last box:

```
.price-view-default:last-child {display:none;}
```

And following code is my assumption for hiding the second to last box:

```
.price-view-default:nth-child(4) {display:none;}
```

However, above code does not work. Does anyone know how to hide box using CSS?

```css
.price-view-default:last-child {display:none;} 

.price-view-default:nth-child(4) {display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="page-inner-container lp_hide_general_plans " id="select_style" data-style="vertical_view_1">    <div class="col-md-4 price-view-default 685  ">
                <div class="lp-price-main lp-border-radius-8 lp-border text-center">                
                    <div class="lp-title" style="background-color: #2caae0;">
                        <div class="lp-plane-top-wrape">
                            <a>Monthly Listing</a>
                            <p>$39</p>
                            <span class="package-type">Per Listing</span><br><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Bottom plan section -->                 
                </div>
    </div>  <div class="col-md-4 price-view-default 687 featured-plan ">
                <div class="lp-price-main lp-border-radius-8 lp-border text-center">

                    <div class="lp-title" style="background-color: #963693;">
                        <div class="lp-plane-top-wrape">
                            <a>Quarterly Listing</a>
                            <p>$99</p>
                            <span class="package-type">Per Listing</span><br><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Bottom plan section -->
                </div>
    </div>  <div class="col-md-4 price-view-default 686  ">
                <div class="lp-price-main lp-border-radius-8 lp-border text-center">                
                    <div class="lp-title" style="background-color: #58ee9e;">
                        <div class="lp-plane-top-wrape">
                            <a>Yearly Listing</a>
                            <p>$329</p>
                            <span class="package-type">Per Listing</span><br><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Bottom plan section -->
                </div>
    </div>  <div class="col-md-4 price-view-default 1765  ">
                <div class="lp-price-main lp-border-radius-8 lp-border text-center">                        
                    <div class="lp-title" style="background-color: #ff8000;">
                        <div class="lp-plane-top-wrape">
                            <a>TEST Listing</a>
                            <p>$1</p>
                            <span class="package-type">Per Listing</span><br><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>              
                    <!--Bottom plan section -->
                </div>
    </div>  <div class="col-md-4 price-view-default 119  ">
                <div class="lp-price-main lp-border-radius-8 lp-border text-center">                        
                    <div class="lp-title" style="background-color: #58ee9e;">
                        <div class="lp-plane-top-wrape">
                            <a>Basic Legacy Listing<br>Limited Time Only!</a>
                            <p>Free</p>
                            <span class="package-type">Per Listing</span><br><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Bottom plan section -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I look at your page it works, both last and second to last box are hidden.

Comment: Your code works, no issues for me when I tested it.

Comment: Try to reset your cache or open the url in incognito.

Comment: Ok, thanks for checking everyone, I cleared my cache and used incognito and other browsers before writing this. I still see it but maybe it is just caught in my router or something. As long as no one sees it I am happy.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `:nth-last-child` selector. Which is the same as `:nth-child`, but counting backwards instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child

```
.price-view-default:nth-last-child(2)
```